# Find the occurrences of a specified letter in a string?

Tags: assembly, x86

```
org 100h

   mov si, 0
   mov di, 0    

back: 

   cmp string[si], 'a'
   inc si

   jz found

   jmp nfound

   found:
   inc di

   nfound:

loop back

ret
  string db 'n','a','n','b','o','N','a','n','a','w','a','g','o','s','h','t','b','o','Q','a','s','a','b'
```

I have also tried to define the string array like this:

```
string db "nan bo Nanawa gosht bo Qasab"
```

the jz coindition is never true, what seems to be the problem? If I remove the si increment instruction the condition does return true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the description of `INC` in Intel's manual you'll see:

> **Flags Affected**
>   The `CF` flag is not affected. The `OF`, `SF`, **`ZF`**, `AF`, and `PF` flags are set according to the result.

So your `jz found` instruction is branching based on the result of `inc si` rather than the result of the `cmp`. I suggest that you move the `inc si` instruction to right before `loop back`.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison result is calculating by checking zero flag.

After `cmp string[si], 'a'` if both are same, then zero flag will be set. So you should use `jz found` immediately after comparison.

In your code you are using `inc si` after comparison, and you lost the comparison result,  in this case if the value of `si` is zero after `increment` then only zero flag will set.